# Como se deben tratar los parametros recibidos en un metodo

Tags: c#, método, buenas-prácticas

Cordial saludo.

Soy estudiante de desarrollo, estoy desarrollando un programa y en una clase tengo un método con varios parámetros, la duda que me surge es que dentro del método como debo tratar esos parámetros ¿los debo asignar a una variable local? o puedo trabajar sobre esos objetos sin necesidad de asignarlos a una variable local.
Ejemplo:
Tengo el siguiente metodo.

```
 public void CambiarTextoTextBox(TextBox textBoxAModificar)
    {
     TextBox textBox=textBoxAModificar;
     textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
     textBox.Text="Hola";  
    }


 public void CambiarTextoTextBox(TextBox textBoxAModificar)
    {
     textBoxAModificar.ForeColor = Color.Black; 
     textBoxAModificar.Text="Hola";
    }
```

Aclaro que yo se que los dos métodos funcionan correctamente, mi duda es que cual es la correcta, cual seria una buena practica.

Comment: No necesitas reasignarlos a una variable local. Es redundante.

Recuerda que los objetos, cuando los pasas por parámetros, no son "copias" del objeto original. Contienen la referencia al objeto original. Da igual cuantas asignaciones hagas, todas modificarán el mismo objeto. Así que lo más sencillo es que actúes directamente sobre el nombre del parámetro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque se que da el mismo resultado tenia la duda de como era la mejor manera de solucionar esto.

Answer (score 2):

Los parámetros en C# se pasan como referencias al original, por lo que si lo asignas a una variable local y los modificas tiene el mismo efecto que modificarlos directamente, es redundante.

Es decir, en tu ejemplo las dos funciones hacen lo mismo. La manera "correcta" sería la segunda, ya que no tiene sentido asignarlo a otra variable y gastar esa memoria en la referencia.

Otra cosa distinta es si quieres utilizar esos parámetro fuera de tu función en esa misma clase, por lo que si que deberias asignarlos a una variable para poder trabajar con ello sin pasarlos como parámetro. Ejemplo:

```
private TextBox textBox;

public void CambiarTextoTextBox(TextBox textBoxAModificar)
{
    this.textBox=textBoxAModificar; // Lo asignamos a la variable de esta clase.
}

public void otraFuncion()
{ 
    // Modificamos el valor como queramos
    this.textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    this.textBox.Text="Hola";  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo tengo mucho mas claro.

Comment: La respuesta solo aplica cuando los parámetros son por referencia, si los parámetros son por valor, se realiza una copia del dato y el original no se modifica.

Comment: y que hacemos con byref? la respuesta esta un poquito incompleta en ese sentido..